# How to get webpage contents using ajax URL

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to get the page using ajax. I have two different problems.. please go through my question..

```js
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
            const url = "https://www.google.co.in/";
            const both = proxyurl+url;

            request.open("GET", both, true);
            
            request.responseType = 'text/html';
            request.send();
            
            
            function rstSrv()
            {
                if(request.status==200)
                {
                    var list=request.response;
                    document.getElementById('get').innerHTML=list;
          console.log(list);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(`error ${request.status} ${request.statusText}`)
                    var list=(`error ${request.status} ${request.statusText}`)
                    document.getElementById('get').innerHTML=list;
                }
            }
```

```html
<div style='length:100%;width:100%;overflow: auto'>
    <button onclick="rstSrv()"> RestCall </button>
    <div  type="text" id="get" style='length:40%;width:100%'></div><br>
```

**Question 1**
Here google URL works good. but for example while using other web page `//https://www.turkish123.com/yemin-episode-20/`, throws 503 error..

**Question 2**
Due to cross-origin I'm using `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`
Is there any other alternative way to access the web page using ajax?

I also tried using

`request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");`

`request.setRequestHeader("X-Alt-Referer", "http://www.google.com");`

`request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.turkish123.com/yemin-episode-20/");`

Didn't work..

Please help...

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header, it's useless in request headers. You can access cross-origin resources with AJAX only if the server providing the resource allows CORS. Use a server to scrape CORS content.

Comment: @Teemu should I run the same thing in the server? like tomcat?

Comment: Yes, with your server-side language, though.

Comment: @Teemu ohh , okay .. I got it now.. Thank you for helping.. I can understand the solution for 2nd question.